# How to rename database is in Standby/read-only mode in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

How to rename database is in Standby/read-only mode in SQL Server? I am getting this error

> To change the NAME, the database must be in state in which a checkpoint can be executed

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to take the database out of Standby / Read-Only mode before you can rename it.

```
RESTORE DATABASE database_name WITH RECOVERY;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but my database should be in Standby/read-only mode because i have to restore diff backup in standby mode daily.

Comment: I am restoring differential backups in standby mode every day so i want to rename the database and it should be standby/read-only mode so that i am able to restore next day differential backup on the database.

but i can do Restore database dbname with Recovery but i can not apply differential restore unless full restore.

please suggest if you have any ideas.

Regards,

Uday,.